# double quote within double quote string while scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, double-quotes

I am scraping several lists such as the following

```
[{"idEquipo":"0201009011", "nombreEquipo":"At. Saguntino", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201009.jpg"},\n   {"idEquipo":"0202137151", "nombreEquipo":"C.D. Roda "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0202137.jpg"},\n   {"idEquipo":"0201017011", "nombreEquipo":"U.D. Alzira", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201017.jpg"}]
```

I am having trouble with the double quote in `"nombreEquipo":"C.D. Roda "A""`and I am getting a SyntaxError. how can I replace the "A" for just A?

I don´t create the list, I get it like that straight from a web page, so what I need is to be able to parse its content.

The link I am scraping from is [link](https://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getEquiposCompeticion&cmp=1261&tmp=2019/2020), my code used to scrape that link is:

```
    page=requests.get("https://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getEquiposCompeticion&cmp=1261&tmp=2019/2020", headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    lista=soup.find("p").text
    lista=ast.literal_eval(lista)
```

or at the end I have also tried instead of `lista=ast.literal_eval(lista)` I type `lista=json.loads(lista)`

for this specific page, if I print lista I get

```
'[{"idEquipo":"0201128221", "nombreEquipo":"Alboraya U.D. "B"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201128.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0203002021", "nombreEquipo":"C.D. Alcoyano "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0203002.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0202001021", "nombreEquipo":"C.D. Castellon, "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0202001.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0203008201", "nombreEquipo":"C.D. Denia "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0203008.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0201290201", "nombreEquipo":"C.D. Don Bosco "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201290.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0202137211", "nombreEquipo":"C.D. Roda "B"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0202137.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0201118201", "nombreEquipo":"C.D. San Marcelino "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201118.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0203848201", "nombreEquipo":"C.F. At. Ciudad de Benidorm "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0203848.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0206096201", "nombreEquipo":"C.F. Celtic Elche "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0206096.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0201411201", "nombreEquipo":"C.F. Inter San Jose Valencia "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201411.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0201338021", "nombreEquipo":"C.F. Torre Levante "B"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201338.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0203526211", "nombreEquipo":"Elche C.F. SAD "B"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0203526.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0203541011", "nombreEquipo":"Kelme C.F. "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0203541.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0201002041", "nombreEquipo":"Levante U.D. SAD "B"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201002.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0201233011", "nombreEquipo":"Racing D\\" Algemesi-global Supply "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201233.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0203558201", "nombreEquipo":"S.C.D. Intangco "A"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0203558.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0201001041", "nombreEquipo":"Valencia C.F. SAD &#39;B&#39;", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0201001.jpg"},{"idEquipo":"0202004051", "nombreEquipo":"Villarreal C.F. SAD "B"", "urlEscudo":"./img/logosClubes/0202004.jpg"}]'
```

Comment: Do you create these lists yourself or do you get them from somewhere and you need to parse them afterwards?

Comment: I get them from somewhere else and I need to parse them.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Reading contents from a web page shouldn't produce a SyntaxError - maybe some other error, but not a SyntaxError. Did you copy-paste contents out of a web page into your source code?

Comment: The link I am scraping from is [link](https://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getEquiposCompeticion&cmp=1261&tmp=2019/2020), my code used to scrape that link is:


    page=requests.get("https://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getEquiposCompeticion&cmp=1261&tmp=2019/2020", headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    lista=soup.find("p").text
    lista=ast.literal_eval(lista)

Comment: I think your problem stems from using: `ast.literal_eval()` Can you `print(lista)` before this step and update your answer with what it contains?

Comment: I also use lista=json.loads(lista), it still doesn't work. Just updated the question including the output of print(lista)

Comment: This page is a JSON document, not HTML. You shouldn't be feeding it to an HTML parser (or to `ast.literal_eval`). Have you tried `page.json()`?

Comment: Thank you!! that is the answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I got from user2357112 supports Monica which was correct is the following:

This page is a JSON document, not HTML. You shouldn't be feeding it to an HTML parser (or to ast.literal_eval). Have you tried `page.json()`

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use both double quotes (") and single quotes (') to denote string literals. To create a string literal including quotes, use e.g.

```
'Some "string"'
```

or escape the quotes, e.g.

```
"Some \"string\""
```